# why there's a for(;;) in AbstractQueuedSynchronize enq(final Node node) method

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

when I read the `AbstractQueuedSynchronize` source code, about the method

```
private Node enq(final Node node) {
        for (;;) {
            Node t = tail;
            if (t == null) { // Must initialize
                if (compareAndSetHead(new Node()))
                    tail = head;
            } else {
                node.prev = t;
                if (compareAndSetTail(t, node)) {
                    t.next = node;
                    return t;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering why there's a for loop since it could be like this:

```
private Node enq(final Node node) {
        Node t = tail;
        if (t == null) { // Must initialize
            if (compareAndSetHead(new Node()))
                tail = head;
        } 
        node.prev = tail;
        if (compareAndSetTail(t, node)) {
            t.next = node;
            return t;
        }
}
```

dose this have something todo with the concurrent?

Comment: An empty `FOR cycle` is actually an infinite loop. There are no command variables, no exit rule and evolution for the command var(s). It's the equivalent of `while(true) { ...};`

Comment: Your example wouldn't compile, as you have a couple of paths (the first `if`, and what happens if none of the outer conditions are satisfied) that don't return anything. It's a way to do a recursive task using an iterative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your re-write is not equivalent code.  In your version, if the call to `compareAndSetHead(new Node())` evaluates to false, `tail` will still be `null` at `node.prev = tail;`

The original, wrapped in the  `for (;;) { ... }` will keep trying until `tail` is non-`null`.

Comment: yeah, I ignore the case compareAndSetHead will return false, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is used to say that what is inside will be executed an infinite amount of times. It is the same as:

```
while(true){..}
```

It means that inside there must be a statement that breaks this infinite execution which can be a *break* or *return*.

In your case that's a *return* statement, and the infinite loop is used to perform the same task until you reach the condition to meet the *return*. This is only valid if there is a progress/change in the state which is used to check the exit condition. In this case the change happens by following the links in a linked list data structure.